# Update a tkinter window in the background

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a python game, and I'd ideally need to create a simple tkinter GUI, composed of a couple of buttons, and a text input.

The format of the game is currently composed of multiple functions, which for the most part start with a `print(something)`, follow by an `input(bunch of stuff\nbunch of stuff\n)`, and finally a sequence of 'if / else' tests to get the input of the user and make another action (usually calling another function)

This is what is looks like currently:

```
        global BatHP
        global HeroDamage
        global Gold
        print("You manage to hit your enemy, inflicting", HeroDamage,"damage!")
        if BatHP - HeroDamage <= 0: #Id Bat dead test
            randnum = random.randint(2,5) #Calculates won Gold
            winsound.PlaySound("GainOr.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC) #Plays a sound
            print("You have killed the bat, and got", randnum,"Gold!\n")
            Gold += randnum #Gives Gold to Hero
            what_next() #Launches the next function
            BatHP = 5
        else:
            BatHP -= HeroDamage #Damage dealt by Hero is applied
            print("The bat has", BatHP,"HP left!\n")
            enemy_attack() #calls the enemy\attack function
```

The issue I have is that I do not know how to add text to my game... I am have tried label, but it doesn't update the window ('printed stuff' that should work with 'label' still don't appear in the window...). Also, with what I've done, the window now crashes when I press a button.

Also, does the window update itself, as in if text is added ('labeled', in that sense), will it be displayed, or do I need to `window.update`. Moreover, I have this issue where I don't know where to put the creation of buttons. if I put them in my current looping system (the one that updates), the buttons will be created indefinitely, but if I put them outside, I get an error, as the command from the buttons are liked to a function which hasn't been discovered yet...

I don't know if this makes sense, but I really need help. Thanks for helping!

PS: Here is the full project, but it is in French (at least for the sentences spoken and variable names):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VSEWdRxDxHxKpdxROWvh54z9hQytYG5J/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bit of demo code as an example of what your game's structure could be. In this example, the screen is wiped clear of all buttons and labels and entries, then you have to make new ones in the next scene. This supports scenes that have different layouts. If you want every scene to just have a button, a label, and an entry, you could change this structure to save you effort creating widgets. Try running this code to see what it does, then look at the code and the comments to learn how it works.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('300x300') # Sets the dimensions of the window
        self.dark_room() # Goes to the first scene, which is created by the function dark_room below

    def new_scene(self, scene, frame, *args):
        # This function will act as a directory, erasing the previous buttons and labels and going to the next function
        frame.destroy() # Destroys the previous frame, which holds all buttons, labels, entries, etc
        goto = { # A dictionary with references to all your scenes. Add each new scene function to here
            'dark_room': self.dark_room,
            'light_room': self.light_room,
            'intro': self.intro
        }
        if args:
            text = args[0]
            goto[scene](text)
        else:
            goto[scene]()

    def dark_room(self, text='You wake up in a dark room. There are matches next to you.'):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.master) # Place a frame in the window, and then make labels/buttons on it. It makes it easier to clear them later
        frame.pack()
        label_text = tk.StringVar() # Use a StringVar to make a label that can have its text changed
        label_text.set(text) # Be sure to change text using the .set() command. Don't use label_text = 'some text'
        tk.Label(frame, textvariable=label_text, wraplength=200).pack()
        tk.Button(frame, text='Look for door', command=lambda: self.new_scene('dark_room', frame, "It's too dark to see.")).pack()
        tk.Button(frame, text='Light a match', command=lambda: self.new_scene('light_room', frame)).pack()

    def light_room(self, text='The match lights up the room. What is your name?'):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        frame.pack()
        tk.Label(frame, text=text, wraplength=200).pack()
        name = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=name).pack() # This entry is linked to the StringVar called name. name.get() will give you the contents of entry
        tk.Button(frame, text='Submit', command=lambda: self.new_scene('intro', frame, name.get())).pack() # Notice we use name.get()

    def intro(self, name):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        frame.pack()
        tk.Label(frame, text='Your name is %s, the fearless adventurer!' % name, wraplength=200).pack()


root = tk.Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really perfect... Now I have to change my blob of code, but it's super cool to have helped me! Also, what does ```command=lambda:``` mean? Thank you once again!

Comment: Using commands with tkinter widgets, the function that you call doesn’t usually accept arguments. Lambda is a way to create a callable function in-line and unnamed (as opposed to using a *def function(args):* block). This lets you call a function with arguments from a tkinter widget.

Answer (score 0):

The full project was too much to look through carefully, but I see a couple of things off the bat.

Printing doesn't go to tkinter labels, it just goes to the console. You can update a tkinter label with new text by linking a StringVar to the textvariable argument of the label. The value of the StringVar can be changed using its set() method.

```
text = StringVar()
label = Label(parent, textvariable=text)
label.pack()
text.set('Hello world!')
```

You have a `while True` loop with an update() at the end, and also a mainloop(). You should choose one or the other, because these accomplish pretty much the same thing. Also, whichever of these the program encounters first (the while loop, in your case) will prevent the program from continuing on to the next, so mainloop() is never being reached.

As for your issue of not knowing when or where to create buttons, you should take a look at this sample code as a skeleton for how to set up a tkinter GUI.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, it builds the GUI in a class. One very useful aspect of this is the **__init__**() function that is called when the GUI window is created. In the example, in the initiation function a button is created. Then, the function that the button triggers is defined below.

Here's a link to the tutorial that the sample code above is from: https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html
Best of luck!

Comment: Alright, so it would be better for me to create a class for my GUI, with the **__init__()**?

And also, for the ```StringVar()```, will it update the text automatically, and change text dynamically?

I was also wondering if the while loop is better than the mainloop(), because I need to have my program change the GUI, by adding text/modifying it, and also modify the buttons, since they will change text for various situations, and also calling another function.

I'll try to modify my code in the following days, as it is quite long... Anyways, thanks a ton for helping me!

Comment: Sorry for asking so much info!

Is there any translation with Tkinter of the ```input```?, using a Entry, and a confirm button... I don't know how to do that...

Moreover, I'm facing an issue as my button is linking a function which is inside my "while loop", and so I can't call that function (says it isn't known), but placing it after the while loop means it will never be reached and take place...

As well, I also can't place it inside the loop, other wise it will create many buttons repeatedly...

Sorry if this is really stupid, but thanks for answering!

Comment: I'm going to answer again with some more demo code for you to look at